# sqlalchemy updating all records ignoring filter

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Have been bug hunting all day and located the following unexpected behaviour with sqlaclhemy (flash-sqlalchemy to be precise).

The code is

```
actionId = 1

DataLists.query.\
    join(Actions, actions.action_id == DataLists.action_id).\
    filter(Actions.action_id == actionId).\
    update({DataLists.dt_cancelled: datetime.utcnow()})

#Updates ALL DataLists!
```

The query (without the update) returns 1 record, yet ALL records are updated.

```
#testing 
rows  = DataLists.query.\
    join(Actions, actions.action_id == DataLists.action_id).\
    filter(DataLists.action_id == actionId).\
    all()

print("rows: {}".format(len(rows))) # outputs 1
```

From what I understand, the update works on the returned rows. Which is not happening, so I must be missing something here.

I have tried to get a copy of the SQL statments, but the update statement doesn't appear to work like a normal query, so

```
sql = DataLists.query.\
    join(Actions, actions.action_id == DataLists.action_id).\
    filter(Actions.action_id == actionId).\
    update({DataLists.dt_cancelled: datetime.utcnow()})
print(str(sql))
```

doesn't work, and returns that 114 rows were updated

Now it turns out that the join isn't infact needed and the query can be written as

```
DataLists.query.\ 
    filter(DataLists.action_id == actionId).\
    update({DataLists.dt_cancelled: datetime.utcnow()})

#testing
rows  = DataLists.query.\ 
    filter(DataLists.action_id == actionId).\
    all()

print("rows: {}".format(len(rows))) # outputs 1
```

strangely (to me anyway) this now works as expected. Just a single row is updated.

So the issue is with the join. But each DataList is joined on a foreign key 'action_id', this is unique and does not ever return multiple rows.

So does the update command not work with a join? Or is there a glaring bug in the above code I am blind to?

Comment: See [Configuring Logging](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html#dbengine-logging) part of the documentation, or just add `echo=True` to the engine creation and you should see the `SQL` statements.

Comment: I have a very similar issue. My query looks something like this: `session.query(someData).filter(SomeData.other_data_id.in_([1]).update(...)`. Looking at the SQL output (generated by adding `echo=True` to the engine builder), it's just an `UPDATE` query with no `WHERE` clause at all.

Comment: Nevermind, my issue was a user error. I construct the query in multiple steps, and forgot a `q =` from `q = q.filter(..)`